# How to model nested streams with conduits?

Tags: haskell, conduit

Let's say we need to sum up groups of numbers stored in a file, where groups are delimited by an empty line. So

```
1
2
3

4
5
```

shoud result in `6 9`.

It seems natural to model this with nested conduits: the outer conduit would split lines into groups of lines, where each group would itself be a source.

However, I don't see this style supported directly in conduit. What is the most idiomatic way to do this with conduits?

Comment: The [`pipes-group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group) and [`streaming`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.1.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:chunksOf) libraries allow this, not sure how to do it with conduit though.

Comment: Is the goal to use nested conduits to make this paralellizable? Because you should be able to use one conduit to split on double newline and then sum the groups.

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic approaches I'd recommend for this. The simple one is to just yield a stream of sum types indicating "another value" vs "newline." The other approach is to use a combinator approach like [withLine](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-10-05/conduit-extra-1.1.9.1/Data-Conduit-Text.html#v:withLine) or [foldLines](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-10-05/conduit-extra-1.1.9.1/Data-Conduit-Text.html#v:foldLines). The latter can be built on top of the former. This approach was originally discussed [in a blog post on foldLines](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/09/folding-lines-conduit).

Below is a complete code snippet showing the sum type and combinator approach. Note that folded (probably a bad name for this) is a general purpose function for transforming into a "nested stream" from a sum type. The approach taken by pipes (based on FreeT IIRC) can likely be used by conduit as well, but as I mention in the blog post, I think it's a more complicated solution than is needed.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import ClassyPrelude.Conduit
import Data.Text.Read (decimal, signed)

sumType :: Monad m => Conduit Text m (Maybe Int)
sumType =
    linesUnboundedC =$= mapMC toMaybeInt
  where
    toMaybeInt "" = return Nothing
    toMaybeInt t =
        case signed decimal t of
            Right (i, "") -> return $ Just i
            _ -> fail $ "Invalid int: " ++ show t

folded :: Monad m => Sink a m () -> Sink (Maybe a) m ()
folded perGroup =
    startGroup
  where
    startGroup = peekC >>= maybe (return ()) (const go)

    go = takeMaybes =$ (perGroup >> sinkNull) >> startGroup

    takeMaybes = await >>= maybe (return ()) (\x ->
        case x of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just y -> yield y >> takeMaybes)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let src = yield "1\n2\n3\n\n5\n6\n\n\n7"
    src $$ sumType =$ (sinkList >>= print)
    src $$ sumType =$ folded (sinkList >>= print)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I had in mind, except 1) I would expect more direct support from the library for this, and 2) this looks like unnecessary CPS; shouldn't `Sink a m () -> Sink (Maybe a) m ()` be called `Conduit (Maybe a) m a`?

Comment: I'm not sure what that exact type signature would mean or how such a function would behave. But one of the motivating factors for this design is so that the combinator (`folded`) has the ability to force flushing of the rest of the substream for cases where the provided function (`perGroup`) doesn't fully consume its input.